# IllegalStateException in android hello world program

Tags: android

i m new to android and just started to write the first hello world code on android studio 1.2.2 and run on the emulator (gennymotion) and i m getting **IllegalStateException**  and in emulator it is showing

> unfortunately ur app has stopped.

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{jewellers.am.com.amjewellers/jewellers.am.com.amjewellers.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

Comment: Please post the logs from logcat

Comment: and maybe also some code

Comment: Please accurately transcribe error messages - I'm pretty sure Android doesn't say "ur app" or if it does, you have a *highly suspect* installation.  As for the problem itself, what about the error message is mysterious?  It seems to be rather self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

This error caused because you had **not** use **AppCompat** theme:

Your application theme must be:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
```

Manifest file looks like this:

```
<application
   android:allowBackup="true"
   android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" >
```

Make sure you have added **AppCompat v7** library in project and you have to extends **ActionBarActivity**.

Hope this will help you.